# Spring's exception translation mechanism not kicking in

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-orm

I have a scenario where I'm deliberately trying to violate a `unique constraint`, expecting Spring's `DataIntegrityViolationException` to be thrown, however it is never the case. 
`javax.persistence.PersistenceException` is thrown with a cause of `org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException` but no Spring Translation Takes place.

The `DAO` and `Service` classes are correctly annotated with `@Repository` and `@Service` and the Repository `@PersistenceContext`ed.

Service:

```
  @Service
  public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
  @Inject private BookDAO bookDao;

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
  public Book createBook(Book book) {
    Book bk = null;
    try {
      bk = bookDao.makePersistent(book);
    } catch (AppDAOException e) {
      throw new AppServiceException(e);
    }
    return bk;
  }
}
```

My Config:

```
<bean id="libmsEMF"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="libmsDS" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="libmsEMF" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="libmsDS" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">

    <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Exception trace:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:289)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.persist(Unknown Source)
  at com.hurontg.common.persistence.AbstractGenericDAOImpl.makePersistent(AbstractGenericDAOImpl.java:103)
  ... 57 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
  at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
  at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
  at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
  at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
  ... 64 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_AUTHOR_TITLE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BOOK'. The duplicate key value is (Jim Corbett, The Temple Tiger).
  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2886)
  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2328)
  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:638)
  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:614)
  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:573)
  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:707)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractQueryReport$StatementProxy.invoke(AbstractQueryReport.java:235)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractQueryReport$StatementProxy.invoke(AbstractQueryReport.java:235)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
  ... 85 more
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem on your own? I am currently facing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely to be that you don't have any PersistenceExceptionTranslator beans in your context which can unwrap Hibernate's JPA Persistence exceptions to see what the cause was.

Try adding a HibernateJpaDialect bean to your application context:

In Java

```
@Bean
public HibernateJpaDialect hibernateJpaDialect() {
    return new HibernateJpaDialect();
}
```

Or in XML

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
```

Hibernate's AbstractEntityManagerImpl wraps Hibernate's exceptions into JPA exceptions *before* Spring performs its translation. HibernateJpaDialect implements Spring's PersistenceExceptionTranslator interface and knows how to unwrap these PersistenceExceptions.

Answer (score 2):

As I told you I have had the same problem couple of days ago. At least in my situation/confguration I have solved the problem by using/implementing the bean [PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcesor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.html).

It can be included in the context this way,

**XML**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

**JAVA**

```
@Bean 
public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() { 
    return new HibernateExceptionTranslator(); 
}
```

Although the documentation says the following, I have been unable to confirm that `LocalSessionFactoryBean` for `Hibernate4` also implements this bean out of the box (I guess it's jut matter of diving into the code).

> All of Spring's applicable resource factories (e.g.
>   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) implement the
>   PersistenceExceptionTranslator interface out of the box. As a
>   consequence, all that is usually needed to enable automatic exception
>   translation is marking all affected beans (such as Repositories or
>   DAOs) with the @Repository annotation, along with defining this
>   post-processor as a bean in the application context.

Comment: I already have PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor in my config.